# Schema aggregate ratings incorrect values

Tags: post

does anyone know why google is reporting incorrect values in this image?

[image]

Comment: Try a span tag instead.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using `http://data-vocabulary.org/Review-aggregate` this is the correct format:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Review-aggregate">
  <span itemprop="itemreviewed">My item</span>
  <span itemprop="rating" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Rating">
    <span itemprop="average">9</span>
    out of <span itemprop="best">10</span>
  </span>
  based on <span itemprop="votes">5</span> ratings.
  <span itemprop="count">5</span> user reviews.
</div>
```

[image]

Using `meta`:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Review-aggregate">
  <span itemprop="itemreviewed">My item</span>
  <span itemprop="rating" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Rating">
    <meta itemprop="average" content="9" />
    <meta itemprop="best" content="10" />
  </span>
  <meta itemprop="votes" content="5" />
  <meta itemprop="count" content="5" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
<meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="5">
<meta itemprop="bestRating" content="10">
<meta itemprop="worstRating" content="0">
```

respectively.

do comment to this answer if it still doesnt resolve.